# How to spell a gerund

Tags: gerunds

Beeing: Research in literature provides a confusing spelling, with one single «e». What is the correct spelling? I mean the gerund of the verb «to be».

Comment: 'Confusing' is opinion-based. It's one of the most common words in English.

Comment: Did any of the dictionaries you checked say anything other than "being" is the correct spelling? If no, then where's the confusion? (If you did find such a source, it should be mentioned in the question.)

Comment: What is the root of the gerund you started with?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean.  Is the verb "bee," like maybe somebody's backformation of a verb from the noun "bee," like in "sewing bee" or "bumble bee," or is the verb actually "be," as in "to be, or not to be"?

Answer (score 1):

[Beeing](http://www.yourdictionary.com/beeing) in an archaic spelling of being.

From : A Collection Of Old English Plays, 1609 Vol. IV., chapter=Everie Woman in Her Humor,

> I know it took not beeing at thy birth: thou hast been merrie, thou hast sounded hoopes, swallowed whiffes, walkt late, worn favours, seene whoresons;

[Beeing](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=beeing&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cbeeing%3B%2Cc0) usage examples from Google Books